# Is chromecast stuck at chrome version 31

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

For my chromecast app I need a few HTML5 APIs that are available (or stable enough) in Chrome >= 33. But `navigator.userAgent` when run in the chromecast dev console reports:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (CrKey armv7l 1.8.17977) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Does the `Chrome/31.0.1650.0` part mean that chromecast devices are running that old version of chrome? If yes can we expect an update in the future?

Comment: Seems like the new current version of chrome on chromecast is 37!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can expect an update in future. Btw, the proper place for these types of questions which are non-technical is our Cat Developer G+ community.